# How can I clear the list of recently accessed documents in Fedora?

Tags: command-line, fedora, gnome

When I click on the `Clear recent documents` item in the GNOME menu, it clears the list of recently used documents (as expected). How can I replicate this functionality from the command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ubuntu Gnome, the recent documents are stored in `~/.recently-used.xbel`.  You can `rm` that file, but Gnome Panel will still show the list.  There's got to be a better way to get the panel to refresh but `killall gnome-panel` will work.

```
rm ~/.recently-used.xbel
killall gnome-panel
```